# How does \w+ select whole word?

Tags: regex

In a simple regular expression, I understand that

```
\w
```

gives a single word character; however, I do not get how adding a plus (+) like so:

```
\w+
```

selects the whole word. In my mind, the plus just means one or more of the word character, so I do not understand how it would expand out to whole words.

Comment: You answered your question.. in the question.

Comment: This is a rare decent question in the regex tag, though kind of a silly one. It works because `+` matches "one or more"... what's not to understand? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `+` is a greedy quantifier. It means that it will match as many characters as possible, even if there are "lesser" matches that would be valid.

In the string `Hello world`, `\w+` matches `Hello` and `world`.

Appending a `?` to it makes it non-greedy and it will be satisfied with the minimal valid match.

In the string `Hello world`, `\w+?` matches every letter separately.

Comment: Ah yes... I didn't understand that the plus sign is a greedy quantifier. It makes sense ti me now!

Answer (score 5):

Similar to how `[0-9]+` means *one or more digits*, where each digit may be different, similarly `\w+` means *one or more word characters*, again where each character may be different. In this normal "greedy" mode it keeps on going until it can't find any more. (You can also make it non-greedy, finding as few as possible while still allowing the regex to match) via `\w+?` in some regex flavors.)

If you wanted what you expect, to require the same character repeatedly, you'd need to use back-references:

`(\w)\1*` - Find any word character, capture it, and then find zero or more of that same character.

---

#### One character at a time example

With the regex `\w+` and the input string `Hello World` the regex will start at the beginning and say to itself, *"Is the next character matched by `\w`? Yes, so we add it to the result and then move forward one character."* Because of the `+` modifier, after doing this once it keeps on doing it, one step at a time, until it cannot find any more. At this point it moves on to the next part of the regular expression (if there is one) or it stops. With just `\w+` this captures all of `Hello` but not the space or `World`.

#### A note on Backtracking

The default `+` modifier enables *"backtracking"*. This is a ([sometimes-expensive](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)) feature of regex that allows you to express your desire simply while giving the best chance of succeeding. For example, if your regex was `\w+l` and your input string was `Hello World`, the regex engine would capture all of `Hello`, and then say *"Oh dear, now I need to find an `l`. There isn't one after the `o`...maybe I went too far?"* It will back up until it has captured `Hell` and see if there is an `l` next (there isn't), and then back up again to just `Hel` and see if there is an `l` next (there is). The end result will be capturing just the string `Hell`.

Even more interesting is the case of the regex `\w+r` and the input string "Hello World". In this case the engine will capture all of `Hello` and see if there is an `r` following it. Since it does not find one, it backtracks one character at a time, until it finds out that `H` isn't followed by an `r` at this point it says *"Maybe starting with the `H` wasn't a good idea"* and goes forward in the string. Eventually it finds `World`, then backtracks to capture just `Wo` and finds that there is, finally, the `r` it needs. At this point it returns `Wor` as the match.

Comment: **Edit**: Added notes on backtracking

Comment: I am slowly starting to get all this, I think. I am amused that all these years that I used grep during my Unix admin days, I never knew about the greediness and backtracking behaviors of regex. I am revisiting this now because of Javascript, and want to make sure I fully understand it. Many thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

When adding the `+` it matches 1 or more of the preceeding tokens.

Its called a `greedy match`, and will match as many characters as possible before satisfying the next token.

http://regexr.com is a great tool for using regex and it also explains what the operators do.